# Can I run cypress with new chrome?

Tags: javascript, e2e-testing, cypress

I need to run cypress in a command line by `run` command. I don`t need to open a real browser. But by default cypress use chrome 58 or lower. If I specify a browser, it opens a chrome. So I need to run tests from the command line without launching a browser, but with a new version of chrome.

Comment: Which cypress version are you using ?

Comment: 3.3.1. Looks like I found an issue. https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/832

Answer (score 0):

`cypress-run` takes a `--browser` argument. Valid values are `chrome electron canary chromium`. Specifying chrome will launch the chrome installed on your machine. Can you show us your command line ?

Comment: yes. But I don`t want to launch a chrome. I want chrome headless.

Answer (score 0):

Cypress is not very likely to be able implement support for this. Chrome developers "decided against implementing extension support in headless mode for now because supporting all the required features is rather complex." (2017) And they keep on skipping it.
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=706008#c5

Since you say "don't need" instead of "can't" I guess you have to run it with Chrome headed or use another browser.